# Trying to read the contents from strstream causes access violation

Tags: strstream

I am trying to read the contents of an ostrstream using the str (). While trying to do so, i always come across access violations and my application crashes. Is there a way to read from strstream without causing stream errors?

I am working on a legacy project built on Borland C++. I am presently using Borland C++ v5.02 for building my project. Since the code is vast and scattered over a large number of files, I am unable to paste the code here. However, I will try to highlight my use case.

ps is the stream which is being used throughout the project to print receipts. I need to get the receipt data from this strstream without breaking the code.

string str = ps.pStr->str ();

ps.Pstr->rdbuf ()->freeze (0);

ps << EndJob;

The last line causes access violation

Comment: Example solution: 
your_stream << std::ends;
your_stream.str();
// using result here
your_stream.freeze(false);

Comment: Thank you Defter. I had an additional question though. What i actually need to do is read from the strstream, get the data and leave the stream in a state where it can be used again. I tried the rdbuf ()->freeze (0) command but after extracting the data the stream cannot be used.

Comment: Please add sample code in your question maybe there some more probem

Answer (score 0):

You missed set null in the end of the buffer.

```
Before any call to str() that uses the result as a C string, the buffer must be null-terminated, typically with std::ends.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Defter. I was not able to use std::ends so i just inserted a null character '/0'. This seems to have fixed the issue. :)